# Split/wrap long words (in hrefs)

Tags: wordbreak

I have a document with lots of `\href`s with very long urls like the following.

Is there a way to force them to split/wrap?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%\renewcommand{\href}[2]{\url{#1}}

\begin{document}

\href{https://ibbw-bw.de/site/pbs-bw-km-root/get/documents_E-219390139/KULTUS.Dachmandant/KULTUS/Dienststellen/ibbw/Empirische\%20Bildungsforschung/Programme-und-Projekte/Wirksamer_Unterricht/IBBW_WU2_Fauth_Leuders\%282022\%29_KognitiveAktivierung.pdf}{{https://ibbw-bw.de/site/pbs-bw-km-root/get/documents\_E-219390139/KULTUS.Dachmandant/KULTUS/Dienststellen/ibbw/Empirische\%20Bildungsforschung/Programme-und-Projekte/Wirksamer\_Unterricht/IBBW\_WU2\_Fauth\_Leuders\%282022\%29\_KognitiveAktivierung.pdf}}

\end{document}
```

My workaround at the moment is `\renewcommand{\href}[2]{\url{#1}}`. But there are also `\href`s with a non url as second argument that I cannot ignore.

Comment: `\href{...}{\nolinkurl{long url}}` ?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks but unfortunately we cannot manually change this. The documents are generated.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer OK. I understand. I can use your hint and redefine like this `\let\oldhref\href` and `\renewcommand{\href}[2]{\oldhref{#1}{\nolinkurl{#2}}}`. Thanks!

Comment: that will only work if your urls don't contain special chars like # or %.

Comment: Why aren't you just using `\url`?

Comment: @Mico see my comment below

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you (a) load the `xurl` package in addition to the `hyperref` package and (b) replace all `\href{<very long string>}{<very long string>}` with just `\url{<very long string>}`.

Oh, and don't escape `%` and `_` characters in URL strings.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\url{https://ibbw-bw.de/site/pbs-bw-km-root/get/documents_E-219390139/KULTUS.Dachmandant/KULTUS/Dienststellen/ibbw/Empirische%20Bildungsforschung/Programme-und-Projekte/Wirksamer_Unterricht/IBBW_WU2_Fauth_Leuders%282022%29_KognitiveAktivierung.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your suggestion is actually the workaround that I was using: `\renewcommand{\href}[2]{\url{#1}}`. But as already mentioned in my question we have also `\hrefs` with a non url text as second argument that I cannot ignore. Furthermore the documents are generated and delivered to us. At this point we have no chance to force the authors to follow the guidelines.

Comment: My current workaround is `\let\oldhref\href` and `\renewcommand{\href}[2]{\oldhref{#1}{\nolinkurl{#2}}}` as suggested by @UlrikeFischer